# Jenkins-Pipeline/Jenkinsfile with Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to integrate Artifactory within my Jenkins-Pipeline/Jenkinsfile. The integration is working, artifacts are getting pushed to my artifactory repos but the retention value is being ignored and the artifacts within the Artifactory repo are growing, and none of them get deleted. My Jenkinsfile with artifactory configuration looks the following:

```
node {
    stage ('Artifactory Test 5.6.2') {

        def server = Artifactory.server 'artifactoryServer'
        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

        rtMaven.tool = "Maven"
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'ci-maven-dev-local', snapshotRepo: 'ci-maven-dev-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'ci-maven-dev-virtual', snapshotRepo: 'ci-maven-dev-virtual', server: server

        checkout scm

        rtMaven.run pom: 'entity-service/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo
        buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 1, maxDays: 7, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
   }
}
```

How to use properly the retention buildInfo? The pipeline above won't delete builds and/or artifacts within Artifactory.

Comment: Artifactory is able to clean up not used artifacts. Additional look here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories for Max Unique Snapshots. So why configure your pipeline to do it? This would be an advantage if snapshots are going to be build from developer computers and jenkins instances.

Comment: but isn't the "retention" s purpose exactly to clean up artifacts and build infos? The Snapshots as you can see are built by jenkins

Comment: You are right. As I never used this I wanted to give you a workaround. Due to it is not an answer to your question I made it a comment ;).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I will try it- a workaround is better than non functioning :)

Comment: Reading a bit further there is an explanation for using buildinfo with maven. There the buildinfo object comes directly from the maven call: def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2'. Maybe that is your problem, that you do a def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo() and not use the one provided from the maven tool

Comment: I tried all combinations, the examples differ in docs and github - the problem was the following: build retention is only supported in pro version ... found that out when trying the same with pro version, it worked directly

Comment: Good to know. That's why we are switching slowly to Nexus. There all kinds of formats (including binaries, npm, docker, etc) are free to use.